# Javascript: Equivalent of PHP's hash_hmac() with RAW BINARY output?

Tags: php, javascript, binary, base64, amazon-product-api

I am connecting to the Amazon Product Advertising API, and to sign my request I need to base64-encode the **raw binary** output of an HMAC-SHA256 hash.

In [the PHP documentation for hash_hmac](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php), the fourth parameter `bool $raw_output` controls whether the output is raw binary data (true) or lowercase hexits (false). My program works in PHP by simply setting that parameter to true.

However, I am now trying to port this over to Javascript. I tried using the CryptoJS.HmacSHA256() function, but it seems to be returning the lowercase hexits. How can I convert this to binary?

I have tried the following according to the CryptoJS documentation, but both outputs are identical:

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("hello", "key");
console.log(hash.toString());
console.log(hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is explained in their [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#The_Hasher_Output). Try this:

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("Message", "Secret Passphrase");

var base64 = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

You need to include http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js for this. If you didn't include this, `CryptoJS.enc.Base64` will be `undefined` and fallback to the default.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ak5Qm/

Comment: I have already tried that, it doesn't seem to work. Please see my revised question for a better explanation.

Comment: @Kevin did you include the base64-min.js? Since it works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/ak5Qm/

Comment: Yes, I have included enc-base64.js from the "components" folder. Even without it there are no errors; is there a way for me to know whether it actually found it or not?

Comment: @Kevin if you use google chrome, press ctrl+shift+j when your page loads and see if there are errors. You can also simply write `CryptoJS.enc.Base64` in your console to see if it's `undefined`

Comment: Like I said, there are no errors. However, the result of writing that IS undefined. Thank you, I'll look into what is causing the issue.

Comment: Yeah I meant, in my chrome at least, the console is populated with error messages for resources (such as scripts) that were not found. Like this: http://i.imgur.com/j6NQI.png

Comment: It turns out I had my scripts included in the wrong order: enc-base64 THEN hmac-sha256, rather than vice versa. Switching this order solved the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha256.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>

Comment: @Esailija I think the fiddle on longer works. Looks like Google moved those scripts

Comment: Note : the CryptoJS HmacSHA256 function supports binary mode by default,

Answer (score 10):

PHP:

```
base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $value, $key, true));
```

Nodejs equivalent:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
let token = crypto.createHmac("sha256", key).update(value).digest().toString('base64');
```

Answer (score 4):

php code

```
echo base64_encode(hash_hmac('SHA1', 'shanghai', '0', true).'beijing');
```

php output

```
xvBv49PpaYvXAIfy3iOSDWNQj89iZWlqaW5n
```

node code

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var buf1 = crypto.createHmac("sha1", "0").update("shanghai").digest();
var buf2 = Buffer.from('beijing');
console.log(Buffer.concat([buf1, buf2]).toString('base64'));
```

node output

```
xvBv49PpaYvXAIfy3iOSDWNQj89iZWlqaW5n
```

Comment: Your code is not clear, what is the key and what is the value?

Answer (score 1):

For the web browser:

```
async hmac_sha1 (str, secret) {
  let enc = new TextEncoder("utf-8");
  let key = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "raw",
    enc.encode(secret),
    {
      name: "HMAC",
      hash: {name: "SHA-1"}
    },
    false,
    ["sign", "verify"]
  );
  let signature = await window.crypto.subtle.sign(
    "HMAC",
    key,
    enc.encode(str)
  );
  let b = new Uint8Array(signature);
  return Array.prototype.map.call(b, x => x.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this npm package to do the same in Javascript.

```
var jsSHA = require('jssha');

hmac_sha1(string, key){
    let shaObj = new jsSHA("SHA-1", "TEXT");
    shaObj.setHMACKey(key, "TEXT");
    shaObj.update(string);
    let hmac = shaObj.getHMAC("B64");
    return hmac;
};
```

Comment: You can put your private key's also into my public library !

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const raw_signature = hmacSHA1(baseString, signingKey);
const signature = raw_signature.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

It's giving the exact same result as, in PHP, :

```
$rawSignature = hash_hmac("sha1", $baseString, $signingKey, true);
$signature    = base64_encode($rawSignature);
```