# How to convert this PHP code into javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cordova

I have some code in PHP:

```
return base64_encode( hash_hmac( self::HASH_ALGORITHM, $string_to_sign, $this->_consumer_secret, true ) );
```

I want to write it in JavaScript. Because I am building an app in Phonegap and PHP does not work in Phonegap.

I had tried this:

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(HASH_ALGORITHM,string_to_sign,consumer_secret);
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
return hashInBase64;
```

here is the php code for signature generate

```
public function generate_oauth_signature( $params, $http_method, $endpoint ) {
        $base_request_uri = rawurlencode( $this->_api_url . $endpoint );

        // normalize parameter key/values and sort them
        array_walk( $params, array( $this, 'normalize_parameters' ) );
        uksort( $params, 'strcmp' );

        // form query string
        $query_params = array();
        foreach ( $params as $param_key => $param_value ) {
            $query_params[] = $param_key . '%3D' . $param_value; // join with equals sign
        }

        $query_string = implode( '%26', $query_params ); // join with ampersand

        // form string to sign (first key)
        $string_to_sign = $http_method . '&' . $base_request_uri . '&' . $query_string;
        return base64_encode( hash_hmac( self::HASH_ALGORITHM, $string_to_sign, $this->_consumer_secret, true ) );
    }
```

So please anyone can help me.

Comment: Maybe phpjs can help: http://phpjs.org/

Comment: i had tried it already

Comment: Do you try `base64_encode` http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_encode/ and `hash_hmac` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099092/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-hash-hmac-with-raw-binary-output ?

Comment: @sulthan. Why do you edit a post to remove what the op has tried?

Comment: @UmNyobe I rolled back the edit from sulthan

Comment: @Thanks Icarus, I was about to do it.

Comment: @umNyobe & Icarus : Thanks. I didn't do that purposely. Done by mistake. Thanks for rejecting the suggestion.

Comment: this is the code for signature genertion of OAuth which i have in php and i am trying to convert it into javascript

Comment: Before trying to dig into this, what was wrong with the result that you tried?  Can you describe how the output was different than what you expected?

Comment: guys do you want to see the code for generate signature may be it will helps you

Comment: just signature is incorrect

Comment: Anything further context that you can provide would be helpful.

Comment: Incorrect in what way?  Is it empty?  Does it produce something that doesn't match what you get out of PHP, but otherwise might look correct?

Comment: okay i will edit my question

Comment: its genrate the signature. same as the php function does but each time signature is different so how can i recognise where the signature is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at how you're using the `cryptojs` function... You're specifying the hashing algorithm in a way the method doesn't appear to support.

This:

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(HASH_ALGORITHM,string_to_sign,consumer_secret);
```

... should be this:

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(string_to_sign,consumer_secret);
```

... because `HmacSHA256` already specifies SHA256 as the `HASH_ALGORITHM`.

Comment: still there is same issue